# Set and get Id on check box

Tags: php, html, webforms

I have an array of ID's that comes from a database. I have also a table like this:

[image]

And the ID array contains record ID, ie:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => GHY87 [description] => Hello World ) )
```

Now I want to check a check box and then click on an Edit Button (Link) to get the ID of that check box.

**NOTE:**

I only want to use php code, not Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: the "Link" he says is http://yfrog.com/1836032774j

Answer (score 0):

Make the edit button a submit button for a form. Each check box is a single element in the form that is submitted. All of them are always submitted.

When a post is received, search through the values posted for on or more that are set to checked.

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

`<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=1> Hello World`

```
<?php
echo "The ID of my checkbox is {$_GET['mycheckbox']}";
?>
```

Maybe you should use a `<select>` box instead.

Answer (score 0):

My simple suggestion:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit();
}
    $ids = array(   
            0 => array(
                    'id' => 1,
                    'code' => 'GHY87',
                    'description' => 'Hello World'
                ),
            1 => array(
                    'id' => 2,
                    'code' => 'OTHER',
                    'description' => 'Bye World'
                )
            );
    function checkboxes($ids)
    {
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="<?php echo $id['id']; ?>" /> <?php echo $id['description'];?> (<?php echo $id['code'];?>)<br />
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <?php checkboxes($ids); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    or
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); return false;">Edit</a>
</form>
```

output:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="1" /> Hello World (GHY87)<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="2" /> Bye World (OTHER)<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
    or
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); return false;">Edit</a>
</form>
```

...if check first checkbox and click Edit, you get:

```
Array
(
    [ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

...if check boths:

```
Array
(
    [ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```